# Invalid OAuth2 redirect_uri

Tags: discord.js

Im making a dashboard for my discord bot on replit with Node.Js but when I click "add to discord/add to server" it says "Invalid OAuth2 redirect_uri" how can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Kind reminder, when asking questions make sure to provide the most amount of details to further assists others in assisting you.

The error derives from the redirect_uri parameter in your oauth2 link not matching with those in the developer portal.

In your developer portal go to OAuth2 -> General -> Redirects 
Make sure you have one created.
Then go to the URL Generator, select your scopes, and then in the option where it says `SELECT REDIRECT URL` set that to the url you just created/selected.

Comment: I don't see select redirect url

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: In the OAuth2 Section of the discord developer portal I dont see "SELECT REDIRECT URL" all I see is client id, client secret, Redirects and Default Authorization Link

Comment: Read my instructions carefully line for line, if you followed them you wouldnt be having that issue.

Comment: I already have one created it just says "add another" im very confused

Comment: Have you saved your changes?

Comment: yes I have it still says "add another"

Comment: Ok, so if its saved and you go to the url generator after selecting your scopes theres a dropdown with redirect uris, pick the uri you're using and go to the link. Note redirect uri's are case sensitive with http/https

Comment: It worked now where do I put the URL?

Comment: The url copied from the developer portal is the url to send to users from whom you want to receive oauth2 info for.

Comment: where in the replit would I put the oauth 2 info redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(`${domain}/window`)}&permissions=490073207` %>' class="add button">Add Bot</a>

Comment: I want to make it so when they click "add to discord it sends the oauth 2 so they can invite the bot